# How to remove auto generated markup?

Tags: html

I'm using a plugin which adds a review box to the post content. There's a problem with the layout of the review box due to auto generated `<p>` and `<br>` tags being added to the markup. I tried a few plugins including this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dont-muck-my-markup/ but they didn't help.

Comment: There is no generic method for removing a plugin's rendered markup. Questions regarding 3rd-party products are considered off-topic here, and would be best addressed in the official support channels for the plugin in question. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template file where it's rendering you can use PHP's strip_tags function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I wonder if I could write a function for this rather than hacking the plugin? How is this even happening? Other people using this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-product-review/) don't seem to be having this problem.